# Creating vectors with indices in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am trying to create 10 vectors with 10 values in each vector and values should have normal distribution. Vectors should be v1, v2, v3 ...

I tried for loop but syntax:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
    v[i] <- rnorm(10)
}
```

didn't work. I tried a lot of varieties of it but with no result and didn't find any solution on web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rarely a good idea to create loads of 'loose' vectors. It is better to collect them in a suitable form, e.g. in a `matrix`, `list` or `data.frame` (a kind of `list`). You can then access individual elements by various subsetting techniques (see `?Extract` and [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

In your case, you may try e.g. `replicate`:

```
m <- replicate(n = 10, expr = rnorm(10))
m
```

This will result in a matrix with `n` columns, where each column is the result of `expr`, i.e. `rnorm(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

In `R` there is no vector of vetors. You can eighther use a 2D analogon a `matrix` or Heterogeneous data structure like `list`
For more details see: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

A `matrix` approach would be:

```
matrix(rnorm(100),nrow=10)
```

A `list` approch would be:

```
lapply(1 : 10, function (i) rnorm(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectors cannot normally be nested (i.e. you cannot have a vector of vectors). R has a special form for that – the `list`.

```
v = lapply(1 : 10, function (i) rnorm(10))
```

Often, you would want to represent this as a `data.frame`, however:

```
setNames(data.frame(v), NULL)
```

(The `setNames` is used to remove the bad column names that R automatically generates otherwise.)